# Is there a tool that makes Windows 7 lighter?

Tags: windows-7

Is there a tool that makes Windows 7 lighter?

I am thinking of a tool much like [98lite](http://www.litepc.com/98lite.html) for Windows 98, which was designed to:

> Tailor your Windows installations to your hardware and needs for
>   substantial improvements in performance, stability, and security by
>   removing superfluous Windows code and features you don't want our use.
>   98lite makes Windows work for you; everything is optional and without
>   risk; previously removed components can be effortlessly added back
>   with a click of your mouse.

That program made a lot of things as an option instead of default.

Answer (score 3):

There is a freeware version of NTLite that supports Windows 7. Of course, you have to know what to remove.

https://www.ntlite.com/features/

Comment: A summary of features might be a nice addition which might save someone a click.

Comment: @Travis This highly depends on what you want. For a OS for benchmarking you would remove a lot more options than for your daily driver e.g.